# Problem with site's search results "Read More" link?

Tags: search, links, excerpt

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with this issue.
I noticed today that when I search certain serch terms in my Wordpress site's search box the link is messed up (shown in the image below outlined by the yellow boxes) and when clicked, the link takes the user to a blank page.

[image: Issue example]

When I searched other terms, either there was the issue on all of the search results for that term or there was no issue at all.

Any ideas what may be causing this and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

probably in your search template file there is a unclosed html tag.

Check into your theme folder the file search.php into foreach loop.

Comment: I went through the file and couldn't seem to find anything that's not closed in the loops :/ .

Comment: Could you post here your search.php content? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check your theme for a filter added to `excerpt_more` or more likely `the_content_more_link`

Chances are there is some error in the coding for a function added to this filter that is limiting the total characters or somehow stuffing up the correct HTML syntax.

Comment: Which file would I look for this in?

Comment: start with your theme's `functions.php`... but it may be included in another theme file or even (less likely) in a plugin somewhere.